# Bootstrap - Alterar fonte

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font

Tenho um sistema com bootstrap e preciso alterar a FONT de todas as páginas.

Tem como alterar isto somente no bootstrap.min.css e não ter que fazer arquivo por arquivo? Como fazer?

O font-family que preciso não é o que já vem de padrão no bootstrap.

Comment: Faça uso do efeito cascata. O efeito cascata determina a prioridade para aplicação da regra de estilo ao elemento conforme descrito a seguir e na ordem decrescente de prioridade: 1 - dentro de uma tag HTML (definidos através do atributo style nos elementos); 2 - folha de estilo interna (definida na seção HEAD da própria página); 3 - folha de estilo externa (importado ou linkado);  Portanto inclua sua folha de estilo alterando a FONTdepois da folha de estilo do boostrap.

Answer (score 3):

Esse é o padrão do `font-family` usado no `body` do Bootstrap 4 como vc pode conferir nesse link:https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Basta substituir a `font-family` no `bootstrap.min.css` nessa classe e vc muda pro site inteiro.

```
body {
  font-family: 'minha-fonte', Helvetica; 
}
```

Vc tb pode fazer um *override* dessa forma, onde no font.css vc declara sua `font-family` no `body`, mas repare que ele tem que vir apos o css do Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="minhafont.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode definir uma classe na tag body ou depois do body criar uma div logo após o body(que é o mais recomendado).

**Não recomendo você fazer alteração no arquivo do bootstrap, mas nada impede de você mexer nesse arquivo**

**Exemplo 1**, você pode referenciar em um arquivo de estilos separados. Neste caso, você faz com que todos os estilos abaixo da sua `div` sejam respeitadas

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../estilos/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet"> //aqui você informa onde está o seu arquivo de estilos
</head>
<body>
<div class="altera-fontes">
              //Aqui estará todo o conteúdo das suas páginas
</div>
</body>
```

E no seu arquivo de estilos ficaria o seguinte código:

```
.altera-fontes {
   font-style: normal; //caso queira deixar alterar o estilo da fonte
   font-size: 2.5em; //caso queira alterar o tamanho da fonte
   font-family: "Times New Roman" //caso queira mudar o tipo de fonte

}
```

**Exemplo 2** Criar um estilo no seu html e fazer a alteração lá mesmo

```
</head>
<style>
   body{
         font-style: normal; //caso queira deixar alterar o estilo da fonte
         font-size: 2.5em; //caso queira alterar o tamanho da fonte
         font-family: "Times New Roman" //caso queira mudar o tipo de fonte
   }
</style>
<body>
```

Nesse segundo caso, você não precisa criar uma classe no CSS, você faz essa alteração no próprio body. (Lembrando que nesse caso não anula o fato de você criar uma classe no seu estilo, apenas mudei o lugar onde o estilo foi criado.)

Estes são apenas 2 das N formas que você pode fazer a alteração.

Para saber de mais informações de classes CSS acesse [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

Caso queira saber mais informações sobre font recomendo esse site [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)

Tente isso e veja se isso funciona para você.